# Sitefinity OAuthLogin sometimes only redirects for Administrator role

Tags: asp.net, redirect, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I have a widget on a Sitefinity 8.0 page that redirects to a login protected page when a child button is clicked.

Most of the time after authenticating, the `OAuthLogin` widget redirects to whatever is specified in the `RedirectUrl` URL parameter. However, once in a while, the `OAuthLogin` widget does not redirect and instead does a postback (looks like a refresh).

What I discovered is that this redirect error never happens for Sitefinity users in the `Administrator` role. My co-worker would have this error happen for him on multiple machines including mine, but my admin account would never experience this.

I'd like to add that the login functionality works because the Sitefinity user is successfully logged in. In fact, after the postback/failed redirect, when the authenticated user clicks logout, the browser then redirects to the specified `RedirectUrl` that it was supposed to go to.

The `OAuthLogin` widget is not a custom widget so I do not have code for that, but maybe someone with more Sitefinity experience can explain what is happening. I have looked at the console for any errors but cannot find any because of the postback that occurs upon clicking the login button. Has anybody experienced this with Sitefinity and is there something I am not understanding about the `OAuthLogin` widget or how `Roles` are applied to page permissions in Sitefinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a probably a bug according to this:

http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/153/Feedback/Details/146549-login-frontend-users-are-not-redirected-to-the-url-specified-in-the-returnurl-qu

So if your current Sitefinity version is below `8.0.5715.0` you may need to upgrade it to version `8.0.5715.0` or above to fix the issue.